# The subject is after the verb in this sentence?

Tags: subjects, objects

"Please hand *me* the comb."

My textbook says to identify what 'me' is, I was able to do that for sentences in which the subject before the verb but I cannot do that for this sentence?

I know that hand is the verb, and the comb is the object but what would me be?

The indirect object?

Comment: The sentence has an elided (implied) subject. Please visit [ell.se]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is better on ELL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me is the indirect object. The subject is you (who is acting), the direct object is comb (what is being acted on), and hand is the verb.

Comment: Using single quotes or appropriate style can make a whole lot of difference. The subject is **not** you. The subject is 'you' (or *you*). The sentence has an elided (implied) subject.

Answer (score -1):

The older concept is differentiating between transitive and intransitive. A more practical concept is about the [valency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valency_%28linguistics%29) of a verb and its hierarchical transitiveness.

Intransitive: valency = 1. Only one object, which is the source but zero targets:

> [1]**He** died.

Transitive: valency = 2. One source object + one target object.

> [1]**She** dyed [2]**her hair**.

Di-Transitive: valency = 3. One source object[1] + one target object[2] + one nested target[3].

> [1]**She** gave [3]**me** [2]**her hair**.
>   [1]**He** wrote [3]**me** [2]**an email**.

Nested transitiveness:

> {[1]**He** wrote [2]**an email**} [3]{**to me**}.

Hyper-transitive adventure of a verb **am** and nested verb **rain**:

> I am afraid it will rain cats and dogs three more days after tomorrow before New Year's through Christmas by lots of havoc with continuous fury, with incessant fear.

```
[1]I am
[2] afraid{
  [4]it will rain {
     ....
}
[3]with incessant fear
```

The complete tree:

```
[1]I am
[2]afraid{
  [4]it will rain {
     [5]cats and dogs
     [6]three more days
     [7]{
       [10]after tomorrow
       [11]before New Year's
       [12]through Christmas
    }
    [8] by lots of havoc
    [9] with continuous fury
  }
}
[3]with incessant fear
```

reflected with more precise numbering

```
[1]I am
[2]afraid{
  [2.1]it will rain {
     [2.1.1]cats and dogs
     [2.1.2]three more days
     [2.1.3]{
       [2.1.3.1]after tomorrow
       [2.1.3.2]before New Year's
       [2.1.3.3]through Christmas
    }
    [2.1.4] by lots of havoc
    [2.1.5] with continuous fury
  }
}
[3]with incessant fear
```

Comment: The 'more practical concept' considers _afraid_ a verb?

Comment: Thanks. Corrected. [1]My brain was [2]tired with [3]too much unaccomplished after [4]a busy day of [5]repetitive experiments [6]not too helpful to [7]my goals.

Comment: The valency tree needs to be more precise -- I'll edit it another day, but currently it still proves the point.

Comment: Does this treatment distinguish true objects from what [Aarts and McMahon](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=xm0isUzM_iIC&pg=PA162&lpg=PA162&dq=%22The+piano+had+a+stool%22&source=bl&ots=tqVbxI8Bps&sig=l55Eo-HOkEUwHhxvHnkWk5Z9vcg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=KjCAUsWhD4-qhAeu-YD4BQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22The%20piano%20had%20a%20stool%22&f=false) claim 'should not be considered objects but are best regarded as belonging to a slightly different category':post-verb noun groups such as appear in: The piano resembled a pianola./The piano weighed a ton./The piano had a stool./The piano seemed an antique. ?